# WinServer 2012R2 - WinRM error -2147014789 0x8007277B

Tags: winrm

On my WinServer 2012R2 Foundation I have a notification in the server manager that the Remote Desktop Connection Broker service is stopped. When I try to start it manually I receive:
Server manager could not start the task due to the following error: Failed to open the runspace pool. The Server Manager WinRM plugin might be corrupted or missing.

In Powershell I tried the following command: winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WSManFault
    Message = A system call has failed.

Error number:  -2147014789 0x8007277B
A system call has failed.

Basically any command I try with winrm returns the same error. I found that the error means: WSASYSCALLFAILURE A system call that should never fail has failed.

Any suggestions please how to fix this?
Thank you very much in advance!
Best regards,
Andy